# Protractor automation:scripts is waiting longer time to execute between the steps

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor

I executed the protractor automation scripts.

After executing the some few lines. script is idle for x seconds(approx 150 sec) and not going to the next line. Every time its happening at the same line

This is scripts was running perfectly in the older version of application. In the newer version i am facing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check manually if you see the same issue if not please post html and the script. You should go step by step and check all locators - maybe html was changed.